# Minimum length of virus signatures

Tags: antivirus, virus, malware, malware-detection, virus-scanning

I haven't found information about this anywhere. Is there a minimal required length for virus signatures? I've read in book by Peter Szor that for 16-bit applications 16 bytes is enough even to avoid false positives. Is there equvilent minimum for 32 and 64-bit applications too?

Thanks.

Comment: Since nobody writes viruses in Assembly any more, I would think 1K would be reasonable ;)  Come to think of it, nobody writes viruses any more, period.

Comment: @MK., nobody writes viruses any more?  Hooray!  Now about that bridge...

Comment: When was the last time you saw a virus?  Not a worm, not an adware, but a real virus?

Comment: Explain... How do you mean nobody writes viruses? I know they are no longer in ASM but C virus is still a virus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**May be my experience useful to you:**

> I generated hex-code signatures using n-gram, opcodes and using menonic. And I used more than 2000 viruses to min signatures. The min length was 16 byte and max size was 68 bytes. Also, for signatures was created for both malware and benign. The approach was **Heuristic and Data-Mining**.
>   The length of Benign signature was less than malware. And i though, it was because Benign are written in high-level language so compiler generated code and more similarity reduce the length of Benign signatures. Where as Malware are written in comparatively Low level (Assembly) or in inline-Assembly (embedded-assembly within high-level language) so produces lengthy signature comparably.
>
> Also long signatures are useful in detail analysis in offline scanning.